# Python django angular JS ng-repeat rows not showing

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I have a piece of angular code within a bigger Python Django HTML page -

```
{% verbatim %}
<div ng-controller="FwCompController">
    <tbody ng-repeat="fwComp in fwCompList">
        <tr>
             <td>
                 <div class="form-group" >
                     <select name="{{mycomp}}" class="compName">
                         <option value="{{fwComp.value}}" selected="true">{{fwComp.title}}</option>
                         <option value="none">None</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" name={{fwComp.pathName}} placeholder={{fwComp.pathPlaceHolder}}/>
                 </div>
             </td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
 </div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Angular -

```
var app = angular.module('boombox', []);
app.controller('FwCompController', function ($scope) {
     this.fwCompList = [
       {
           name: "compName1",
           value: "mba",
           title: "UEFI",
           pathName: "compPath1",
           pathPlaceHolder: "/hsc_sw_dvt/rels/mba/7.10.70/evpxe.nic",

       }];
     $scope.mycomp = "compName1";
});
```

The table rows do not get printed in the resulting HTML page. Why ? Is it valid to assign angular vars as HTML attribute values ?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the `fwCompList` to `$scope`

```
$scope.fwCompList = [
   {
       name: "compName1",
       value: "mba",
       title: "UEFI",
       pathName: "compPath1",
       pathPlaceHolder: "/hsc_sw_dvt/rels/mba/7.10.70/evpxe.nic",

   }];
```

In your legacy code, you bind `fwCompList` to `this`, which is your controller `FwCompController` but not `$scope`. If you don't want to change your controller, you should change your HTML to

```
<div ng-controller="FwCompController as fw">
    <tbody ng-repeat="fwComp in fw.fwCompList">
```